# Regex replace with capturing a repeated group

Tags: java, regex, groovy, intellij-idea

I have the following Java code snipped:

```
def offer = new OfferBuilder().id(1)
                              .rulesId(1)
                              .secondaryRulesId(0L)
                              .code("test code")
                              .characteristics([characteristics])
                              .build()
```

I would like to replace it with the following Groovy:

```
def offer = new Offer(id: 1, rulesId: 1, secondaryRulesId: 0L, code: "test code", characteristics: [characteristics])
```

I'm using Intellij built-in regex to replace:

```
new (\w+)Builder\((\)\s?\.(\w+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9\" \[\]]+))+\).build\(\)
```

Replacement string:

```
new $1($3: $4)
```

The problem is that I can only replace last occurrence of matched groups, so that it outputs:

```
def offer = new Offer(characteristics: [characteristics])
```

I've been trying to use capturing on repeated gruoup, but still can't make it work. Can you please advise what's missing?

Comment: You might get an answer of the [IntelliJ forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/ideacommunity)

Comment: Sadly, most regex flavors don't offer the feature you want here. :\

Comment: You need a programming language here to take the repetition out of the regex

Answer (score 0):

Here;
regex definition;

```
regex :  new\s+OfferBuilder\(\)(\.[^\s]*\([^\s]*\))*
```

detect your :

```
new OfferBuilder().id(1)
                              .rulesId(1)
                              .secondaryRulesId(0L)
                              .code("test code")
                              .characteristics([characteristics])
                              .build()
```

for object parameters use :

```
(\.[^\s]*\([^\s]*\))*
```

then you parse every matching parameters.